# Hadoop Multi Master Cluster Setup

Tags: hadoop

We have a Hadoop setup with 2 Master nodes and 1 Slave node.

We have configured the Hadoop cluster. After configuring, when we executed "jps" command, we are getting following output on my Master Node:

```
13405 NameNode
14614 Jps
13860 ResourceManager
13650 DataNode
14083 NodeManage
```

On my second Master Node, output is:

```
9698 Jps
9234 DataNode
9022 NameNode
9450 NodeManager
```

On my Data Node, output is:

```
21681 NodeManager
21461 DataNode
21878 Jps
```

I feel my secondary node is not running. Please tell me this is right or wrong. If its wrong, what should be the status of my node? Please answer me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can check status of node by running below command
`hdfs haadmin -getServiceState`

Comment: Hello I am not getting any service please tell me if you know an other idea

Comment: did you get any error while formmating standby namenode`hdfs namenode -bootstrapStandby`